# wordpress json parsing in android

Tags: android, json, wordpress

I am not getting the posts in my Android app. This is my source code for MainActivity.

I am running this app directly on my Android Device. And also Internet connection is enabled on my Device. It only shows loading posts and mothing happens.. :(

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView postList;

ArrayList<String> postArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> postAdapter;
Context context;
String feedUrl="http://www.aurangabadhq.com/?json=get_recent_posts";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context=this;
    postList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.postList);
    postAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.post_list_item, postArrayList);
    postList.setAdapter(postAdapter);
    PostListTask loaderTask=new PostListTask();
    loaderTask.execute();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public class PostListTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Loading Posts...");
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest=new HttpGet(feedUrl);
        try {
            HttpResponse response=client.execute(getRequest);
            StatusLine StatusLine= response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode=StatusLine.getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode !=200 )
            {
                return null;
            }
            InputStream jsonStream=response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            String jsonData=builder.toString();
            JSONObject json=new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONObject object=new JSONObject("object");
            JSONArray posts=new JSONArray("posts");
            for(int i=0;i<posts.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject post=posts.getJSONObject(i);

                postArrayList.add(post.getString("title"));
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to get Json from web?

Try  this:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");
for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject post=posts.getJSONObject(i);
     postArrayList.add(post.getString("title"));
}
```

Not sure if this will work, as I haven't checked your json. I would suggest to try to Log jsonData string, to see if you even get your json from network.

Comment: Thanx for quick response.. but still.. It shows nothing.! please check my json.. I guess there is no error in code.. you can check my json here, "http://www.aurangabadhq.com/?json=get_recent_posts"

Comment: So if you put Log.d("YourApp", jsonData); 

just after while statement, does anything show up in Logcat?

Comment: ddms: Can't bind to local 8600 for debugger
ddmlib: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
 at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)

Comment: com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:342)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:521)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:831)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:799)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:617)
 at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
 at$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:576)